# What causes HARDWARE_FEEDBACK usage of vibration?

Tags: vibration, haptic-feedback

Not infrequently I'll experience vibrations seemingly without cause on my Android 13 Pixel 6 Plus. After a particularly busy period, I had `dumpsys vibration_manager` tell me what had been happening; I excerpt the most relevant portion below. *Something* seems to be repeatedly triggering, for about 200Ms each, vibrations for hardware feedback. What does the usage HARDWARE_FEEDBACK describe? How can I track that description further back to the original cause (and hopefully stop it).

```
  Previous vibrations for usage HARDWARE_FEEDBACK:
    startTime: 09-25 08:45:43.540, endTime: 09-25 08:45:43.742, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:45:46.269, endTime: 09-25 08:45:46.470, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:45:47.900, endTime: 09-25 08:45:48.101, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:02.346, endTime: 09-25 08:46:02.547, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:03.918, endTime: 09-25 08:46:04.118, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:05.221, endTime: 09-25 08:46:05.422, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:06.199, endTime: 09-25 08:46:06.400, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:07.245, endTime: 09-25 08:46:07.445, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:08.254, endTime: 09-25 08:46:08.455, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:09.263, endTime: 09-25 08:46:09.464, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:10.559, endTime: 09-25 08:46:10.760, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:11.508, endTime: 09-25 08:46:11.709, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:12.674, endTime: 09-25 08:46:12.875, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:13.731, endTime: 09-25 08:46:13.932, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:14.875, endTime: 09-25 08:46:15.076, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:16.051, endTime: 09-25 08:46:16.253, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:17.036, endTime: 09-25 08:46:17.238, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:18.181, endTime: 09-25 08:46:18.381, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:19.473, endTime: 09-25 08:46:19.674, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:20.492, endTime: 09-25 08:46:20.693, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:21.470, endTime: 09-25 08:46:21.671, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:22.776, endTime: 09-25 08:46:22.976, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:24.071, endTime: 09-25 08:46:24.272, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:24.994, endTime: 09-25 08:46:25.194, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:26.043, endTime: 09-25 08:46:26.244, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:27.461, endTime: 09-25 08:46:27.661, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:29.043, endTime: 09-25 08:46:29.244, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:30.564, endTime: 09-25 08:46:30.765, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:32.144, endTime: 09-25 08:46:32.345, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:33.742, endTime: 09-25 08:46:33.943, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:34.842, endTime: 09-25 08:46:35.043, durationMs: 202, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:35.872, endTime: 09-25 08:46:36.072, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:36.916, endTime: 09-25 08:46:37.117, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:37.932, endTime: 09-25 08:46:38.132, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:38.966, endTime: 09-25 08:46:39.167, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:40.707, endTime: 09-25 08:46:40.908, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:41.973, endTime: 09-25 08:46:42.174, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:42.982, endTime: 09-25 08:46:43.183, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:44.573, endTime: 09-25 08:46:44.774, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:46.281, endTime: 09-25 08:46:46.482, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:47.642, endTime: 09-25 08:46:47.843, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:48.636, endTime: 09-25 08:46:48.837, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:49.972, endTime: 09-25 08:46:50.172, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:50.968, endTime: 09-25 08:46:51.169, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:52.785, endTime: 09-25 08:46:52.986, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:53.937, endTime: 09-25 08:46:54.138, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:56.573, endTime: 09-25 08:46:56.773, durationMs: 201, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
    startTime: 09-25 08:46:57.560, endTime: 09-25 08:46:57.761, durationMs: 200, status: finished, effect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, originalEffect: Mono{mEffect=Composed{segments=[Step{amplitude=-1.0, frequencyHz=0.0, duration=200}], repeat=-1}}, scale: 0.00, attrs: VibrationAttributes: Usage=HARDWARE_FEEDBACK Audio Usage= USAGE_UNKNOWN Flags=0, uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc, reason: null
```

Comment: *"What does the usage HARDWARE_FEEDBACK describe?"*. Hardware keys, navigation keys, fingerprint sensor, NFC sensor, charging started, device wake up etc.

Comment: Well, drat. That doesn't narrow it down very much at all. I was hoping for a better lead.

Comment: Your log clearly indicates that all vibrations are due to `uid: 1027, opPkg: com.android.nfc`. So it must be the NFC sensor causing vibrations.

Comment: I did not see that's what it was plainly telling me. That is a /great/ lead!

Comment: @IrfanLatif, do you want to write that up as the actual solution, so I can credit you for it?